# Let $A$ be a dense subset of $X$ and suppose $A$ is connected in the induced subspace topology, then $X$ is also connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

> **PROBLEM**
>
> Let $A$ be a dense subset of $X$ and suppose $A$ is connected in the
> induced subspace topology, then $X$ is also connected

**ATTEMPT**

Suppose $X = U \cup V $ for open, nonempty, disjoint $U,V$. By Denseness of $A$, $Cl(A) = U \cup V $. We know that $A \subseteq Cl(A)$. Hence $A \subseteq U \cup V $. Well, here it is pretty obvious that $A $ must be $U \cup V$ and hence having a contradiction. But I think probably I need to prove this obvious thing. Can someone help me? Is this approach correct?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

HINT: No, $A$ need not be $U\cup V$. Consider the sets $U\cap A$ and $V\cap A$.

Comment: But this still gives contradiction since they are disjoint

Comment: @DonAnselmo: You have to do a little more work than that. They are certainly disjoint. Are they open in the subspace topology on $A$? And are they non-empty?

Comment: Yes they are open since in the subspace induced topology, open sets  are of the form $O \cap A$ where $O$ is open in $X$. they are nonempty since $U$ and $V$ are nonempty

Comment: @DonAnselmo: You still have to say a little more to justify the assertion that they’re non-empty. After all $(0,1)$ is a non-empty open set in $\Bbb R$ that has empty intersection with lots of subsets of $\Bbb R$!

Comment: ok so if $U \cap A = \varnothing $ then $U$ is in $X - A $, but I have proved before in another problem that this implies that $A$ is not dense. contradiction!

Comment: @DonAnselmo: There you go: now you have a complete argument. (In fact my preferred definition of ‘$A$ is dense in $X$’ is that every non-empty open set in $X$ has non-empty intersection with $A$.)

Comment: @DonAnselmo: My pleasure!