# set in a connected space is connected

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, connectedness

I want to prove that if $X$ is a connected space, then $Y\subset X$ is connected.

is the following proof correct?

**[Edit: corrected error]**

Take $U\subset Y$ an open set of $Y$. Then $U = Y\cap U'$ for some $U'$ open in $X$.

Suppose that $U$ is closed in $Y$. Then $U^c = Y - U= Y\cap U'^c$ is open in $Y$ which means that $U'^c$ is open in $X$. Therefore, $U'$ is closed in $X$. So $U' = X$ and $U = Y$. So $Y$ is connected.

Comment: $U^c\neq X\cap U'^c$

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer which makes it more correct and can't see the problem know.

Answer (score 4):

First you should know that the statement is false, take $X=[0,1]$ and $Y=\{0,1\}$ clearly $X$ is connected but $Y$ is not.

So your proof is wrong. The wrong part is that $U^c = X\cap U'^c$.

Why? for example, if $U=\{0\}$ then $U$ is open in $Y=\{0,1\}$ and $U=Y\cap U'$ for $U'=[0,1/2)$. But $X\backslash{U'}^c = [1/2,0]$ and $U^c = [0,1)$.

Comment: Ok. I edited my answer which makes it more correct and can't see the problem know.

Comment: However, would this be true if $Y$ where open?

Comment: no, even if $Y$ open you can take $Y=[0,1/3)\cup (2/3,1]$.

Comment: The assertion in the Q that "...$Y\cap U^{'c}$ is open in $Y$ which means that $U^{'c}$ is open in $X$ " is also erroneous. If $V$ is open in $X$ then $V\cap Y$ is open in $Y,$ but the converse is not valid . (For example let $V=Y$, with $Y$ not open in $X.$)

Answer (score 2):

What you were trying to prove is almost never true. Actually:

**Theorem:** Every Hausdorff topological space with more than one point has a disconnected subspace.

**Proof:** Take $x,y\in X$ with $x\neq y$. Then $\{x,y\}$ is disconnected.

---

You should keep in mind that the idea of “connected” is that it's all in a single block (as opposed to being scattered in several blocks). So, what you were trying to prove was that if a set is all in a single block, then every subset has the same property. Not likely, don't you think?

The error in the edited version of your proof lies in the (false) implication$$Y\cap U'^c\text{ open}\implies U'^c\text{ open in }X.$$For instance, $(0,2)\cap(1,3]$ os open in $(0,1)$, but $(1,3]$ is not open in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: ok thanks for the theorem. Is it true if my subset is open?

Comment: @tomak No. $\mathbb R$ is connected and $(0,1)\cup(2,3)$ is an open disconnected set.

Comment: @tomak: I think what you have in mind is a dense subset of a connected space. In this case your claim is true. Also see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/550039/let-a-be-a-dense-subset-of-x-and-suppose-a-is-connected-in-the-induced-sub

Answer (score 1):

There are already excellent answers, but to an other one:

Consider the Cantor set in $\mathbb R$ with Euclidean topology. $\mathbb R$ is connected whereas the Cantor set clearly is not.

Comment: the rationals $\mathbb Q$ are dense in $\mathbb R$, but not connected (unless you consider uniform, or Cantor, connectedness: http://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1964-015-03/S0002-9939-1964-0161307-7/S0002-9939-1964-0161307-7.pdf and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniformly_connected_space )

Comment: Yes. You’re quite right. I’ll remove that part. Thanks